# Nativescript slider height increase for android

Tags: android, nativescript

I am trying to increase the height of the slider but I am unable to do so. I also couldn't find anything about this. I tried via XML code and also JS code but both don't seem to do the job.

Here is my XML code:

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
    <StackLayout>
        <Slider id="sli"minValue="0" maxValue="100" value="50" color="#D81F26" height="20"></Slider>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
var getViewById = require("tns-core-modules/ui/core/view").getViewById;
pageLoaded = function (args) {
  const page = args.object;
  var slider = getViewById(page, "sli");

  slider.android.setProgressTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList.valueOf(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#D81F26")));
  slider.android.setPaddingRelative(0, 0, 0, 0);
  slider.android.layout(0, 0, 0, 10);
  slider.android.setMinHeight(20);
  slider.android.setMaxHeight(20);
}
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Slider relies heavily on Drawables, you will have to adjust the height of individual drawable & layers. The best way would be designing your own drawable and apply it via native Theme. If you still like to just adjust the height at run time, you could do this

```
const drawable = slider.nativeView.getProgressDrawable();
for (let i = 0; i < drawable.getNumberOfLayers(); i++) {
    drawable.setLayerHeight(i, 30);
}
```